# How do I access successive rows from mysql_fetch_assoc() in a different file and array variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm trying to implement a simple "list-out" functionality from a table of places/spots of a city.

To do this, I created a Place class and returned a `mysql_fetch_assoc()` array from a "get" function. This code is in a PHP file called "placeops.php", containing only OO logic.

Now moving to another file called "displayplaces.php", I call the same "get" function here to get the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` array into another variable. Then I use the `next()` and `current()` functions to retrieve the records.

This doesn't work. If I use `current()` to get a specific column/attribute value, it says "current() expects array, string passed" error. By NOT using `current()`, I can only access the first element, as expected. I understand why that error comes. But is there any workaround for this? I have to use OO approach. Here's the code:

```
//This is the class and the function I use to return the mysql array. The file name is
//   placeops.php

<?php


//include '../../../myclass.php';
@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("wom") or die(mysql_error());

global $plcname, $plcaddr, $plccity, $plcstate, $plcpic, $plcrating, $plclat, $plclong, $plccat, $plcid;

class Place
{

    private $pname;
    private $paddr;
    private $pcity;
    private $pstate;
    private $plat;
    private $plong;
    private $prating;

    function getAllPlaces()
    {

        $plcqry = "SELECT * FROM place,state,city where place.st_id = state.st_id AND place.ct_id = city.ct_id";
        $rows = mysql_query($plcqry);
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($rows);

        /*
        while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows))
        {
            $GLOBALS["plcname"] = $res["plc_nm"];
            $GLOBALS["plcstate"] = $res["st_nm"];
            $GLOBALS["plccity"] = $res["ct_nm"];
            echo $GLOBALS["plcname"]." -- ".$GLOBALS["plccity"]." -- ".$GLOBALS["plcstate"]."<br><br>";
        }
         * */

    }

    function getPlace($name, $city, $state)
    {

        $this->pname = $name;
        $this->pcity = $city;
        $this->pstate = $state;

        $row = mysql_query($plcqry);
        $plcqry = "SELECT place.plc_nm, place.plc_photo, place.plc_addr, place.ct_id, place.plc_lat, place.plc_long, city.ct_nm, state.st_nm FROM place,state,city WHERE place.plc_nm = '".$this->pname."' AND place.st_id = state.st_id AND state.st_nm = '".$this->pstate."' AND place.ct_id = city.ct_id AND city.ct_nm = '".$this->pcity."'";

        @$row = mysql_query($plcqry);

        $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);

        $GLOBALS["plcname"] = $res["plc_nm"];
        $GLOBALS["plcaddr"] = $res["plc_addr"];
        $GLOBALS["plccity"] = $res["ct_nm"];
        $GLOBALS["plcstate"] = $res["st_nm"];
        $GLOBALS["plcpic"] = $res["plc_photo"];
        $GLOBALS["plclat"] = $res["plc_lat"];
        $GLOBALS["plclong"] = $res["plc_long"];

        //echo "".$GLOBALS["plcname"]."<br>";// <img src=\"".$GLOBALS["plcpic"]."\"/>";
    }

    function ratePlace($name,$city,$state,$rating)
    {        

        $this->pname = $name;
        $this->pcity = $city;
        $this->pstate = $state;
        $this->prating = $rating;

        $plcqry = "SELECT place.plc_id, place.plc_rating FROM place,state,city WHERE place.plc_nm = '".$this->pname."' AND place.st_id = state.st_id AND state.st_nm = '".$this->pstate."' AND place.ct_id = city.ct_id AND city.ct_nm = '".$this->pcity."'";
        $row = mysql_query($plcqry);
        $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
        $GLOBALS["plcrating"] = $res["plc_rating"];
        $GLOBALS["plcid"] = $res["plc_id"];

        $rating += $GLOBALS["plcrating"];

        $ratingqry = "UPDATE place SET plc_rating = ".$this->prating." WHERE plc_id = ".$GLOBALS["plcid"]."";
        mysql_query($ratingqry);

        $plcqry = "SELECT plc_rating FROM place WHERE plc_id = ".$GLOBALS["plcid"]."";
        $row2 = mysql_query($plcqry);
        $res2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($row2);
        $GLOBALS["plcrating"] = $res2["plc_rating"];    
    }

    function getPlaceByRegion($city, $state)
    {
        $this->pcity = $city;
        $this->pstate = $state;

        $plcqry = "SELECT place.plc_id, place.plc_nm, state.st_nm, city.ct_nm FROM place,state,city WHERE place.st_id = state.st_id AND state.st_nm = '".$this->pstate."' AND place.ct_id = city.ct_id AND city.ct_nm = '".$this->pcity."'";
        $rows = mysql_query($plcqry);

        while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows))
        {

            $GLOBALS["plcname"] = $res["plc_nm"];
            $GLOBALS["plcstate"] = $res["st_nm"];
            $GLOBALS["plccity"] = $res["ct_nm"];
            //echo $GLOBALS["plcname"]." -- ".$GLOBALS["plccity"]." -- ".$GLOBALS["plcstate"]."<br><br>";
        }
    }
}

?>

    //And this is the other part of the code, which I use in another PHP file that
    //contains the HTML code ("view layer"). File name is "displayplaces.php"
    <?php
        include './placeops.php';
        $obj = new Place;

        $res = $obj->getAllPlaces();
        while (next($res))
        {
          //expected string parameter errors for all these assignments
          $GLOBALS["plcname"] = current($res["plc_nm"]);
          $GLOBALS["plcstate"] = current($res["st_nm"]);
          $GLOBALS["plccity"] = current($res["ct_nm"]);
          $GLOBALS["plcrating"] = current($res["plc_rating"]);
          $GLOBALS["plclat"] = current($res["plc_lat"]);

          echo "<tr>
                  <td>" . $GLOBALS["plcname"] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $GLOBALS["plcrating"] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $GLOBALS["plccity"] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $GLOBALS["plcstate"] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $GLOBALS["plclat"] . "</td>
               </tr>";
        }

    ?>
```

Currently there are 14 records in the table. And I know I can workaround this by writing the sql handling code in the "displayplaces.php" file itself. But is it possible to keep the function and display logic different? May be use an extra index in `$res` array? Or do I have to write the fetching code in the same PHP page that displays the content?

Comment: I've only pasted the code for the method and the method call. Rest assured I've added other OO code up there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with the use of objects here. Primarily, this is not actually object oriented. You can do this without the use of globals at all - objects should contain their data internally.

I would expect a class called `Place` to contain just one place, but you are offering a method called `getPlaces` which does not seem to fit with that purpose. I'd suggest you create another class called `PlaceSet` (or similar pluralisation) that contains a number of `Place` objects in an array.

Something like this:

```
class Place {
    // I've stored some example properties here, you can
    // change these if you wish
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $state;
    protected $city;

    // I've used a constructor here, but you could use a setter function
    // instead, so that a Place can have its properties changed during its
    // lifetime
    public function __construct($id, $name, $state, $city) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->city = $city;
    }

    public function ratePlace($rating) {
        // You can access $this->id to set a rating
    }

    // Offer getters in this format
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class PlaceSet {
    // This function just returns an array of Places, but you could
    // also store that result in this class if you wish, so as to
    // reuse it without having to rerun the query every time
    public function getAllPlaces() {
        // Word-wrap your long lines!
        $plcqry = "
            SELECT *
            FROM place,state,city
            WHERE
                place.st_id = state.st_id
                AND place.ct_id = city.ct_id
        ";
        // @todo This legacy library needs to be swapped out
        $rows = mysql_query($plcqry);

        $places = array();
        while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows))
        {
            $places[] = new $Place(
                $res["plc_id"]
                $res["plc_nm"],
                $res["st_nm"],
                $res["ct_nm"]
            );
        }

        return $places;
    }

    // Maybe this should be getPlacesByRegion?
    //
    // Always declare your access level
    public function getPlaceByRegion($city, $state)
    {
        // Add code here
    }

}
```

You can access the full list of places thus:

```
<?php
    // Do your connection here

    include './placeops.php';
    $placeSet = new PlaceSet();

    $places = $placeSet->getAllPlaces();
    foreach ($places as $place) {
        // Add these getters into the Place class
        echo "<tr>
              <td>" . $place->getName() . "</td>
              <td>" . $place->getRating() . "</td>
              <td>" . $place->getCity() . "</td>
              <td>" . $place->getState() . "</td>
              <td>" . $place->getLat() . "</td>
           </tr>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: I've done just that. Only I've included the getAllPlaces() function in the Place class itself. I've only pasted that part of the code here which is causing the problem.

Comment: There you go. I've added the remainder of the code. And about using ***@mysql_connect()***, I'm still not well-versed with using mysqli or PDO. Hence I cannot use them. I neither have the time to learn them. Currently I have to stick to Procedural API.

Comment: Thanks. I notice it still contains globals, which need to be removed entirely. If you look at `getPlaceByRegion` it overwrites the globals in the loop. In any case, something that "gets" data should `return` it, and not affect global state.

Comment: I've updated the code with more ideas @Meet. Of course, you could do this in Propel or Doctrine, if you are in fact building an ORM. As for `mysql` functions, you might have a SQL injection vulnerability in this code, so you should look into that at least.

Comment: 1stly, about the get functions returning a value - I had just finished testing all the get functions with echo(), and started with getAllPlaces() to actually return the array, and encountered this problem. That is why most of them don't have a return statement.

2ndly, I will conform to your code suggestions. Only I will keep all the functions in the Places class itself, for my own reasons.

3rdly, you have suggested using an array of objects. How do I access that object? With foreach() or for()? And also, I simply want to display the place data. Wouldn't creating object for each be improper?

Comment: No worries @Meet, pleased it helped.